# Redirect in SimpleForms

Tags: bolt-cms

Using SimpleForms I define a page to use in

> redirect_on_ok: page/thank-you

I get this error:

> Call to undefined function Bolt\Extension\Bolt\SimpleForms\simpleredirect()

(Bolt 2.02, bolt/simpleforms 0.10)

Can this be repaired?

*PS Gawain if you read this, I'd love to give your extension a try sometime, but the SimpleForms documentation is more readable for me at this moment.*

Answer (score 0):

I think you found a bug in the simpleforms extension, it is already reported https://github.com/jadwigo/SimpleForms/issues/2

--

the bug is fixed in the latest version of bolt

Comment: BTW I also have a suggestion for that green box when used with longer pages/forms. You could make the form action direct to #confirmation and give the box id="confirmation" so it's always in the viewport. You might want to add something like that in the default files.